# Outofmemory while fetching messages from content provider in pagination

Tags: android, pagination, garbage-collection, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to build a single fragment(inside an activity ofcourse) application, which displays all the messages like the default messages app. There is a recyclerview in a `MessageFragment`. `MessageRecyclerViewAdapter` is the adapter for the same. I think the culprit is `MessageRecyclerViewAdapter`. `mValues` will have a map of id to sms. But the keys are being removed `mValues` as soon as the viewholder is detached or recycled. So, I think all the references to sms are being removed when it's removed from recycler view, but the memory keeps on increasing almost linearly as I scroll down and results in OOM. What am I missing? (I'm a backend developer, learning android for context)

```
class MessageRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private val mListener: OnListFragmentInteractionListener?,
    private val recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    val context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageRecyclerViewAdapter.MessageViewHolder>() {

    private val mOnClickListener: View.OnClickListener
    private var mValues: LinkedHashMap<Int, Sms> = LinkedHashMap()
    private var mPositionToIdMap: MutableMap<Int, Int> = mutableMapOf()

    private var count: Int? = null

    init {
        mOnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { v ->
            val id = v.tag as Int
            // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the fragment is attached to
            // one) that an item has been selected.
            mListener?.onListFragmentInteraction(mValues[id])
        }
    }

    fun setCount(count: Int) {
        this.count = count
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, position: Int): MessageViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, parent, false)
        return MessageViewHolder(view, position)
    }

    //This will pass position to onCreateViewHolder, instead of viewtype
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = position

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holderMessage: MessageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val sms: Sms? = mValues.get(mPositionToIdMap[position])

        if (sms == null) {
            Log.e("MRVA", "sms == null")
            return
        }
        val addressText = String.format("%s (%s), id:%s, %s", sms.address, DateTimeUtil.format(sms.date), sms._id, position)
        Log.e("addressText", addressText)
        holderMessage.mAddressView.text = addressText
        with(holderMessage.mView) {
            tag = sms._id
            setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener)
        }
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onDetachedFromRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        mValues = linkedMapOf()
        mPositionToIdMap = linkedMapOf()
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: MessageViewHolder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
        remove(holder.mPosition)
    }

    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: MessageViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
        remove(holder.mPosition)
    }

    fun add(
        sms: Sms,
        id: Int,
        position: Int
    ) {
        mValues[id] = sms
        mPositionToIdMap[position] = id
    }

    fun remove(mPosition: Int) {
        mValues.remove(mPositionToIdMap[mPosition])
        mPositionToIdMap.remove(mPosition)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = count ?: 0

    fun getId(position: Int): Int? = mPositionToIdMap[position]
    fun hasData(position: Int): Boolean = mPositionToIdMap.containsKey(position)
    fun getBottomMostPositionWithData(): Int {
        var position = 0
        mPositionToIdMap.forEach { entry ->
            position = entry.key
        }

        return position
    }

    fun getTopMostPositionWithData() = mPositionToIdMap.iterator().next().key
    fun get(id: Int) = mValues[id]

    inner class MessageViewHolder(val mView: View, position: Int) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mView) {
        val mAddressView: TextView = mView.address
        val mPosition = position
    }
}
```

```
class SmsUtil {

    private final val CONTENT_URI: String = "content://sms/inbox"

    fun readAllMessages(
        context: Context?,
        epoch: Long? = null,
        limit: Int? = null,
        smsHandler: SmsHandler
    ) {

        val cursor = getCursor(context, epoch, limit) ?: return
        processSms(cursor, smsHandler)
    }

    private fun processSms(
        cursor: Cursor?,
        smsHandler: SmsHandler
    ) {
        if (cursor == null)
            return
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    val sms = getSms(cursor)
                    Log.v(ContentValues.TAG, "SMS read $sms")
                    smsHandler.handle(sms)
                } while (cursor.moveToNext())
            } else {
                Log.v(ContentValues.TAG, "The user does not have any sms")
            }

        }catch (e: Exception) {

        } catch (e: Error) {

        } finally {
            cursor.close()
        }
    }

    private fun getCursor(context: Context?, epoch: Long? = null, limit: Int? = null): Cursor? {
        val selection = if (epoch != null) String.format("%s > %s", Sms.COLUMN_DATE, epoch) else null
        val sortOrder =
            if (limit != null) String.format("%s desc limit %s ", Sms.COLUMN_DATE, limit) else null
        //above will be compiled into sql . SELECT * FROM sms_restricted WHERE (type=1) AND (_id > 100) ORDER BY  limit 100
        return context?.contentResolver
            ?.query(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI), null, selection, null, sortOrder)
    }

    private fun getSms(cursor: Cursor?): Sms? {
        if (cursor == null)
            return null
        val sms = Sms()
        sms._id =
            cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_ID))
        sms.threadId =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_THREAD_ID))
        sms.address =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_ADDRESS))
        sms.person =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_PERSON))
        sms.date =
            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_DATE))
        sms.dateSent =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_DATE_SENT))
        sms.protocol =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_PROTOCOL))
        sms.read =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_READ))
        sms.status =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_STATUS))
        sms.type =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_TYPE))
        sms.replyPathPresent =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_REPLY_PATH_PRESENT))
        sms.subject =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SUBJECT))
        sms.body =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_BODY))
        sms.serviceCenter =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SERVICE_CENTER))
        sms.locked =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_LOCKED))
        sms.errorCode =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_ERROR_CODE))
        sms.seen =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SEEN))
        sms.subId =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_SUB_ID))
        sms.creator =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_CREATOR))
        sms.priority =
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Sms.COLUMN_PRIORITY))
        return sms
    }

    fun getCount(context: Context?): Int {
        val cursor = getCursor(context) ?: return 0
        val count = cursor.count
        cursor.close()
        return count
    }

    fun getLatestMessages(
        context: Context?,
        epoch: Long? = null,
        limit: Int? = null,
        smsHandler: SmsHandler
    ) {
        if (context == null)
            return
        val selection = if (epoch != null) String.format("%s > %s", Sms.COLUMN_DATE, epoch) else null
        val sortOrder =
            if (limit != null) String.format("%s asc limit %s ", Sms.COLUMN_DATE, limit) else null
        val cursor = context.contentResolver
            ?.query(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI), null, selection, null, sortOrder)
        processSms(cursor, smsHandler)
    }

    fun getOldestMessages(
        context: Context?,
        epoch: Long? = null,
        limit: Int? = null,
        smsHandler: SmsHandler
    ) {
        if (context == null)
            return
        val selection = if (epoch != null) String.format("%s < %s", Sms.COLUMN_DATE, epoch) else null
        val sortOrder = String.format("%s desc limit %s ", Sms.COLUMN_DATE, limit)
        val cursor = context.contentResolver
            ?.query(Uri.parse(CONTENT_URI), null, selection, null, sortOrder)
        processSms(cursor, smsHandler)
    }
}
```

Comment: `override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int = position` – I would suspect that that's at least part of the problem. That's basically disabling `RecyclerView`'s recycling mechanism, and a new `ViewHolder` instance is created for every single item. `//This will pass position to onCreateViewHolder, instead of viewtype` – You don't need to pass the position to the `ViewHolder` like that. Simply use `adapterPosition`/`absoluteAdapterPosition` there.

Comment: yes, that's the problem, thanks!